# Clustering nodes based on different readings at different times using K-Means

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to cluster nodes based on a data set consists of different readings for each node at different times.

here is an example of my data:

```
1.0000   21.0860   46.1968    2.3000    2.3568
1.0000   21.0762   46.0326    0.9200    2.3568
1.0000   21.0664   45.9669    0.9200    2.3568
2.0000   89.5488   29.2581   11.9600    1.9537
2.0000   19.5670   39.6878  121.4400    2.6753
2.0000   19.5376   39.7557  121.4400    2.6753
2.0000   19.4788   39.6878  121.4400    2.6633
```

where 1 in the first column indicates data for node 1 and 2 indicates data related to node 2.

How can I force K-Means to cluster the data while all the data points for node 1 fall into the same cluster and so on.

**NOTE** The goal is to cluster the nodes not the data.

Here is my code in MATLAB where I did not consider the node labels and simply clustered the data which is actually not desired:

```html
filename = 'data.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn);
data = A.data;
DATA_REAL = A.data(1:n,3:end);

temperature = DATA_REAL(:,1);
humidity = DATA_REAL(:,2);
light = DATA_REAL(:,3);
voltage = DATA_REAL(:,4);

%% 2 Dimension

% K-means Algorithm for 2D %%

[KM_R2,C_R2,sumd_R2,D_R2] = MY_KMEANS(DATA_REAL(:,1:2),K);

figure
plot(temperature,humidity,'r.')
hold on
grid on

Nodes_in_Cluster = zeros(1,K);

for j = 1:K
    Nodes_in_Cluster(j) = length(find(KM_R2==j));
end

for i = 1:length(DATA_REAL)
    text(temperature(i),humidity(i),num2str(KM_R2(i)),'BackgroundColor',cc(KM_R2(i),:));
end
title(['Number of clusters in K-means:',num2str(K)])
xlabel('temperature')
ylabel('humidity')
```

Any advise in MATLAB or Python is appreciated.

If you think K-Means is not proper for this type of clustering what is your suggestion.

Thank you,

Comment: Which one is it, Python or MATLAB? Please show your code. Why do you need to cluster your data at all if you've already got labels on your data? Also, screenshots are particularly unhelpful. It's really hard to copy and paste data from a screenshot.

Comment: I edited the question by removing the screenshot. Although I have labels for data, I want to cluster the nodes since there are almost 100 nodes and I want to have almost 5 clusters.

Comment: What weighting do you need among the nodes?  Does a node with 20 data points outweigh a node with only three?  If not, then your first task is to pre-process the data, replacing each node with its centroid.  Then simply cluster the centroids.  Also, change the node number to a string, and take that column out of the distance formula.

Comment: @Prune No the weighting is not important. I though the same way as you explained. However I am looking for any other idea or algorithm that can do all by itself. I mean finding the centroid for one label and clustering the nodes afterward.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you walk through a tutorial on Python's SciKit package.  This has a lot of nice ML tools, including K-Means and centroid functions.  NumPy will help you set up a nice matrix from your data and manipulate it to your liking.

In general, you'll want to

1. Find the centroid for each node, collapsing your data to about 100 rows.
2. Use the SciKit k-means clustering function, leaving the first column (node number) out of the consideration; you don't want the node ID being part of the distance computation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variant called uncertain k-means that you can try.

In theory, you assume that all different readings of each node are equally likely (you could also use weights). Then you draw a random reading for every node to measure distances, and repeat this very often (in theory, the methods directly compute what sound happen if you do this infinitely often, I believe). That way, you can cluster nodes as in regular k-means.